Decay of tail moment of normal distribution
$\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\bE}{\mathbb{E}}$
Let $X_t$ be a normal random variable on $\bR^d$ with mean $0$ and variance $tI_d$ for $t>0$. Here $I_d$ is the $d$-dimensional identity matrix. For $R>0$, let $B_R$ be the closed ball with center $0$ and radius $R>0$. Let $B_R^c := \bR^d \setminus B_R$. I would like to obtain some decay rate of moment of $X_t$.

Is there a "tight" and explicit function $f : \bR_+ \times \bR_+ \to \bR_+$ such that $\bE [ | 1_{B_R^c} X_t | ] \le f (t, R)$?

Any reference is appreciated. Thank you for your elaboration.

I think you need to clarify which norm you use for the ball and what is meant by variance $t$. Do you mean that $X_t \sim N(0, t I_d)$?

@DrewBrady Yess, I have clarified my question.

First, you may assume $t=1$ since $$\mathbb{E} [ | 1_{X_t\in B_R^c} X_t |]=\sqrt{t}\mathbb{E}[| 1_{X_t/\sqrt{t}\in B_{R/\sqrt{t}}^c} X_t/\sqrt{t} |]$$ and $X_t/\sqrt{t}$ has the same distribution as $X_1$. Then, you can compute the expectation in polar coordinates:
$$
\mathbb{E} [ | 1_{X_1\in B_R^c} X_1 |]=\frac{\text{Area}(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})}{(2\pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}}\int_R^\infty r^ne^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}\,dr.
$$
Now you can integrate by parts as in the estimation of Gaussian tails:
$$
\int_R^\infty r^ne^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}\,dr=-\int_R^\infty r^{n-1}de^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}=R^{n-1}e^{-\frac{R^2}{2}}-(n-1)\int_R^\infty r^{n-2}e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}\,dr
$$
Since the second term above is negative, the first one gives an upper bound. If you continue similarly integrating by parts, the signs will alternate, giving sharper lower and upper  bounds on your expectation. Note that for even $n$, the resulting asymptotic series does not converge for any fixed $R$.
For $n$ odd, and the above series terminates at $n=1$, i.e., the integral is elementary.

$\newcommand\Ga\Gamma$Note that $|X_t|^2/t$ has the $\chi^2_d$ distribution, which is the gamma distribution with parameters $d/2,2$. So, after straightforward manipulations, we get
$$E|1_{B_R^c}X_t|=\frac{\sqrt{2t}}{\Ga(d/2)}\,\Ga\Big(\frac{d+1}2,\frac{R^2}{2t}\Big), \tag{1}\label{1}$$
where $\Ga(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the incomplete gamma function. There are a great many good upper (and lower) bounds on the incomplete gamma function (see e.g. this paper and references therein), which, in view of \eqref{1}, immediately give good upper (and lower) bounds on $E|1_{B_R^c}X_t|$.
